# Access 64bit registery keys from a 32bit application

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

So I've been looking at the class from: http://www.wpfsharp.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/

Although this doesn't provide a function for OpenSubKey to be a "Directory" (not sure what it is called)

I need to scan through all the keys in that location(Find all the firefox versions).

What I've got:

```
RegistryKey localMachine = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox", false);
string[] installedVersions = localMachine.GetSubKeyNames();
```

Now this works fine on a 64bit application with .net 4.x framework.
But running it on a 32bit application with .net 2.0 framework it returns null.

Upgrading isn't really an option, and I'm sure it must be able to do it with current settings, I just don't know how.

P.S I'm aware of the possible crash because in this snipper I don't handle the fact that localmachine can be null. But I do in the real application.

Comment: You have about fifty good reasons to set the EXE project's Platform target to AnyCPU.  If you really, really can't do that then you'll have to use pinvoke.

Comment: @HansPassant It's already on any cpu. But the solution has in it's configuration set that this project uses x86. I wan't every system, even old ones using 32 bit to be able to run it. With almost no dependencies(that's why I'm using .net 2.0)

Comment: The solution platform name is completely irrelevant to a C# project, only the Platform target setting the Build tab matters.

Comment: @HansPassant So how exactly would I do it using p invoke? I also tried this: https://dotnetgalactics.wordpress.com/2010/05/10/accessing-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-process/
Didn't work either unfortunately

Comment: Clearly you actually have a hundred good reasons to use AnyCPU.  Use Task Manager to verify your app runs in 64-bit mode, use SysInternals' Process Monitor to verify that you are reading the correct registry key.